# How to use a LatLng to a Google Maps Activity

Tags: java, android, dictionary, android-intent, gps

I need to use the Latitude and Longitude I get on LocationChanged to show on MAP the position at the time, but I'm not sure how to pass it!

I've used Intent.putExtra but it brakes down my application, but i don't really know why (I still get the coords when I don't use "map.putExtra("Latlng", Local);") but adding it breaks my app, help please

```
 //map is the name of the Intent of the google maps Activity
 @Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    TextView coords=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view_coords);
    double latitude=location.getLatitude();
    double longitude=location.getLongitude();
    coords.setText("Latitude:"+Location.convert(latitude,Location.FORMAT_SECONDS)
            +"\n" +
            "Longitude:"+Location.convert(longitude,Location.FORMAT_SECONDS));


    LatLng Local = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    //Passar o Bundle referente ao LatLng criado anteriormente.
    map.putExtra("Latlng", Local);

}
```

----------------------MapsActivity ---------------------

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
double lat;
double lng;
LatLng objLatLng;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

    objLatLng=getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("Latlng");


    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    //Recebendo do objeto LatLng as coordenadas em DOUBLE referentes a Latitude e a Longitude
    lat = objLatLng.latitude;
    lng = objLatLng.longitude;

    //Referentes a marcação e setagem da posição atual na API do Google Maps
   LatLng PosAtual = new LatLng(lat, lng);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(PosAtual).title("Sua posição atual!"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(PosAtual));
}
```

}

Comment: Pass the latitude longitude...separately as Double

Answer (score 0):

try to pass it as separate like below

```
map.putExtra("latitude", latitude);
map.putExtra("longitude", longitude);
```

And on get on MapsActivity activity like below

```
double lat = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("latitude");
double lang = getIntent().getDoubleExtra("longitude");
```

or  putParcelable method to attached LatLng Object to a Bundle

```
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("Latlng", Local);
map.putExtra("bundle", args);
```

To get in MapActivity like

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getParcelableExtra("bundle");
LatLng objLatLng = bundle.getParcelable("Latlng");
```

Comment: is getDoubleExtra supposed to receive only one parameter?

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro sorry didn't get you

Comment: here getDoubleExtra expects an String and a Double value, like "getDoubleExtra(String, double);

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro yes getDoubleExtra has 2 value string for key and double for default value like getDoubleExtra("doubleValue_e1", defaultValue)

Comment: it stil doesn't work, it is probably something wrong, that is not that, thanks anyway

Comment: one last thing, do i put the map Intent as a atributte or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is that

```
LatLng Local = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
```

is not parcelable and you got to convert this into some String using `Gson` and then pass it to bundle and convert it back to object using again Gson

or just pass *lat* *long* alone using

```
putExtra("lat",latitude)
putExtra("long),longitude)
```

Comment: it still stops even with metod